# Material-UI TextField variant label striking through value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am trying to use `TextField` component from Material-UI with the outlined variant, but for some reason the label goes straight through the value? How can I fix this?

[Screenshot of TextField with label and value mixed up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T5Vm.png)

I reproduced it in below codesandbox.io:

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-borg-2ojel?file=/src/App.tsx

#### App.tsx

```
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField variant="outlined" label="Label" value="Vest" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

### package.json

```
    "@material-ui/core": "4.12.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3"
```

Comment: Strange the codesandbox you provided renders fine. What browser are you using?

Comment: latest version of Chrome on Windows

Comment: You could split the TextField into InputLabel & OutlinedLabel. The codesandbox you provided renders fine for me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}` to force the "shrink" state of a `TextField` control, which in this case should render the label on the outline of the field.

```
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField variant="outlined" label="Label" value="Vest" InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```